# Google PubSub subscription with Python API: how to create a generator out of a subscription that can be processed locally?

Tags: python-3.x, stream, generator, google-cloud-pubsub

I searched for an example in the github repo but to no avail. 
The application I have in mind is to "stream" a subscriber -- read, to emulate a Python generator so I can window the stream before processing it.

Any hints on how to create a generator out of a pubsub subscriber? Or perhaps suggestions of other python frameworks that can assist me with the same topic (window processing in streams coming from pubsub/kafka etc.)

Comment: The application I have in mind is to listen to a pubsub stream and create windows dynamically based on some key (say device id for an IOT app) before passing the keyed window to a function.  I haven't figured out how to create a python generator out of a pubsub subscriber yet (or what would be the kafka equivalent of a consumer).  All of this using the python apis for google pubsub. 

If you have any experience on advice on window computing on streams it would be much appreciated.